# Symfony2/Assetic: Use bundle annotation in asset path for imported HTML files

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

I am using Symfony 2.8 for my single page web application. I have a file `index.html.twig` which is supposed to serve all the required resources. Maybe it's obvious, but I want everything to be reloaded every time in the development environment, but not in the production environment. Said required resources is loaded from another bundle's `Resources` located in the `vendor` folder.

For this reason, I have configured Assetic in `config.yml` as stated below:

```
assetic:
    debug: "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller:
        enabled: "%kernel.debug%"
    workers:
        cache_busting:
            enabled: "%kernel.debug%"
```

(I am assuming that debug is only enabled in the development environment)

I am loading the required CSS/JavaScript like this:

```
{% stylesheets
    '@StubbornShowaBundle/Resources/public/stubborn.css'
    '@StubbornShowaBundle/Resources/public/showa.css' %}
        <link type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endstylesheets %}
{% javascripts
    '@StubbornShowaBundle/Resources/public/stubborn.js'
    '@StubbornShowaBundle/Resources/public/showa.js' %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

..which seems to be working as intended. However, I also have imported HTML files. Like this one:

```
<link href="{{ asset('@StubbornShowaBundle/Resources/public/polymer/my-component.html') }}" rel="import"/>
```

However, the above code does not work. The `@StubbornShowaBundle` annotation seems like it is not usable in the `asset` command. Also, there seems to be no "loop method" (or whatever you want to call that thing for `stylesheets`, `javascripts` and `images`) for HTML imports. If I link to the file in question directly, aside from stooping to an ugly hack that completely breaks uniformity with the surrounding code, I also break the whole Symfony/Assetic automatically taking care of resource reordering system and debugging becomes a mess. How do I solve this in a way that doesn't force me to re-dump the assets every time I change the code while debugging? (Is it possible to solve in a reasonable way?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible to use HTML imports in Assetic the same way it's used for JavaScript, CSS and images. [To quote from the manual](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/assetic/asset_management.html):

> You can use Assetic to process CSS stylesheets, JavaScript files and images.

What should be done instead depends very much on the case(the requirements) as far as I can see. Perhaps making everything into templates is also a possibility, but in my particular case I had to import Polymer components so making those HTML files into templates would have been a nightmare(because of the conflicting syntax, and whatnot).
So I got the path using `url`, and used the method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415828/serving-static-html-in-symfony2-with-variable-route#40418405).

Answer (score 1):

After assets:install && assetic:dump you can just link to it like:

```
href="/bundles/stubbornshowa/polymer/my-component.html"
```

just have a look at the

```
/web/bundles/
```

directory

if you are just updating files you can use assetic:dump --watch or assetic:watch

if you put new files into your ressources you have to call assets:install

in /web forlder you could also just create a folder maybe called "uploads" 
and put your stuff there, you can link to it by href="/uploads/..." 
then you dont need any assetic at all

Comment: Perhaps my explanation was insufficient, but I am aware of the fact that I can install and dump. What I want to know is how to link to my HTML imports directly, ideally in the same fashion as stylesheets and javascripts with a bundle annotation.

Comment: you should separate your assets from your templates,assetic is for using assets like js, css, img´s, fonts aso. and for templating use twig! ;-)

Comment: You are right that twig should be used for templates, and that templates should not be mixed in with assets, but not everything that is HTML is a template. HTML just means it is a file written in HyperText Markup Language, which in my case is a polymer component and an external library.

Comment: in /web forlder you could also just create a folder maybe called "uploads" and put your stuff there, you can link to it by href="/uploads/..."

Comment: assetic clearly only for js css and images and no problem to use webdir

Comment: As you say, it is possible put source files in a directory called "uploads" and link to it, and they will be accessible, but that would be very bad practice since it is misleading to put something that is not "uploads" in a directory called "uploads", but more importantly, it has nothing to do with what I am asking for. (See the "If I link to the file in question directly" part of my question) If you provide evidence for your statement that "assetic clearly only for js css and images", then you will have answered my question, and I will accept your answer.