# Serving static html in Symfony2 with variable route

Tags: symfony

In Symfony2's `routing.yml`, I understand it's possible to route to a static HTML page, like this:

```
my_static_route:
    path:     /mycomponent
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template:    @StubbornShowaBundle/Resources/public/imports/component.html
```

My question is, is there any way to do variable routing in `routing.yml` using `FrameworkBundle:Template:template`?

Like this(doesn't work, just an image of what I want to do):

```
my_static_route:
    path:     /mycomponents/{file}
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template:    @StubbornShowaBundle/Resources/public/imports/{file}
```

And then `/mycomponents/foobar.html` would load `@StubbornShowaBundle/Resources/public/imports/foobar.html`

Is that possible? (And if so, how do I do that?)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create custom controller:

```php
namespace Stubborn\ShowaBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;

class StaticController extends Controller
{
    public function streamAction($filename)
    {
        try {
            $path = $this->container->get('kernel')->locateResource('@StubbornShowaBundle/Resources/public/imports/' . $filename);
            $response = new BinaryFileResponse($path);

            return $response;
        } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(sprintf("File '%s' not exists!", $filename));
        }
    }
}
```

And define route like:

```yaml
my_static_route:
    path:     /mycomponents/{filename}
    defaults:
        _controller: StubbornShowaBundle:Static:stream
```

Comment: This seems to render the template as a twig resource. The reason I suspect so is because Symfony throws exception errors when you load Polymer files, which uses the same mustache syntax as Twig.

Comment: I do not want to use `BinaryFileResponse` since it's for serving files(see the Symfony API docs), but I replaced `$response = new BinaryFileResponse($path);` with `$response = new Response(file_get_contents($path));` and that does pretty much what I want, so I'll give you an upvote for giving me 90% of the answer.
(If you fix the part about `BinaryFileResponse` I will consider it 100% of the answer and accept it)

Comment: I won't change my answer, because – technically – you **are** [serving static files](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#serving-files).

Answer (score 0):

Let the template decided by controller. You can pass variable `file` to Controller.

```
// In your TemplateController.
public function templateAction($file)
{
    return $this->render('@StubbornShowaBundle/Resources/public/imports/' . $file);
}
```

This way, the dynamic template file name received from the url will be rendered.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem is, I do not want to render a dynamic template file, but serve static HTML.

Comment: You can put the static HTML in several files. Just pass the file name in the controller to render that particular HTML file. Here file name is dynamic for controller not HTML.

Comment: No offense, but you seem to be misunderstanding the problem. You say "pass the file name in the controller to render that particular HTML file", but rendering it is exactly what I want to avoid. You are using `Controller`'s function `render`, and to quote the Symfony API manual, that function "Renders a view."

Comment: Any specific reason, why you want to avoid rendering an HTML view?

Comment: One specific reason would be that there are cases where certain HTML files are not written with the premise that they will be processed with twig, meaning they might contain unintentional use of twig syntax, which causes errors(To give a concrete example, Polymer).
A more general reason would be the fact that it is completely pointless to render something which itself is the result of a template-rendering, and that it makes no sense to me whatsoever to render something because I have no reason not to, if anything it seems like a line of reasoning that invites an increase in technical debt.

Answer (score 0):

You could either have a template that managed everything or use it to delegate to other secondary templates.

```
{% extends 'WhatEver.html.twig' %}

{% block something %}
    {# handle in template #}
    {% if 'value' == file %}
        <ul>
            <li>{{file}}</li>
            <li>Whatever</li>
            <li>You</li>
            <li>Would</li>
            <li>Have</li>
            <li>In</li>
            <li>The</li>
            <li>Template</li>
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <div class="alert">
            File "{{file}}" not recognised!
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    {# delegate to separate template #}
    {{ include('@StubbornShowaBundle/Resources/public/imports/' ~ file, ignore_missing = true) }}
    {# or maybe (to add the extension) #}
    {{ include('@StubbornShowaBundle/Resources/public/imports/' ~ file ~ '.html.twig', ignore_missing = true) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The question is specifically about routing to static HTML, as opposed to using templates.